# Start a service after an event, even if the app isn't running?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I developed an app which reacts when the device receives an sms. I use a brodcastReceiver, when the device received an SMS it starts an intent for answering the sender.

My problem: 
when the app is already launched : the receive and answer an sms is executed very well.
But when the app isn't launched.nothing happens when device receives the SMS. I d'on't know why?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){  
receive(context,intent);//identifie les éléments du SMS
if(
     (PhoneNumberUtils.compare("+436", phoneNumber) & messageBody.contains("Vous avez recu") & messageBody.contains("Votre solde est de")) //airtel money
     || messageBody.contains("TUMA JESUS") //validation
  )
{
  Intent i = new Intent(context, actionService.class);
  i.putExtra("messageBody", messageBody);
  i.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
  i.putExtra("receivedate", ""+receivedate);
  i.putExtra("brodcast", true);
  context.startService(i);
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver class="com.fasoessential.paymanage.SmsReceiver"     
     android:name="com.fasoessential.paymanage.SmsReceiver"> 
           <intent-filter > 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
 </receiver>
```

Comment: How is your receiver declared in the manifest?

Comment: how did you register your receiver?

Comment: In my manifest:            <receiver class="com.fasoessential.paymanage.SmsReceiver"
   android:name="com.fasoessential.paymanage.SmsReceiver">
   <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

For starting a service when SMS is received, check for these points -

1. Add these permissions to your manifest (WRITE_SMS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS)
2. DO NOT update the manifest with the receiver intent filter !

hope this helps you.

Comment: I have already done it. But when the App is not launch, and it doesn't react when a SMS comes (excuse me for my english)